# Storing and querying location (coords) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, location

In my user schema I have a location column which will hold the last updated coordinates of the user. Is there a PostgreSQL data type I could use to allow me to run SQL queries to search, for example something like: `SELECT username FROM Users WHERE currentLocation="20 Miles Away From $1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "location" column holds GPS coordinates then basically your only option is to use the PostGIS extension. With PostGIS you store your locations in a column with `geometry` or `geography` data type  and then you can apply a rich set of function on it. Your query would become something like:

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE ST_Distance(currentlocation, $1) = 20; -- careful with units
```

This is assuming that `$1` is of the same data type as `currentlocation`. You probably have to convert the miles to kilometers, depending on your coordinate reference system and the data type (`geography` would produce kilometers, `geometry`produces whatever unit the data is in).